# How do I define collections of basic types in Waterline standalone?

Tags: collections, sails.js, waterline

I'm using Waterline `0.13.5` *standalone* with `sails-google-cloud-datastore` (Google Firestore in datastore mode). I've read https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/associations, googled around, etc, and can't find the way in Waterline >= 0.13 to store collections of basic types (strings, numbers, etc).

What's the database adapter-agnostic way of doing that? If there isn't one, how can I have my document (if going against a document store Firestore, MongoDB, OrientDB, etc) contain a field of type array where xxx is any basic type?

Posts on SO & elsewhere use the `array` attribute type, but it's no longer supported in recent versions of Waterline.

Comment: Here is a guide I found: https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/standalone-waterline-usage

Comment: @streleckify I wasn't looking for an RTFM to the existing docs, really.  I've already been through them multiple times.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood what you were looking for. As far as making columns of collections, I would suggest using an embed with JSON data type.